# Подскажите что означает эта строка?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int m[] = { 5, -2, 3, -3, 8, -1, 0 }; /// 0  положительное мнж

    std::sort(std::begin(m), std::end(m),
        [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a >= 0 && b < 0; }); 

    for (const auto& e : m) std::cout << e << ", ";
}
```

`[](const auto& a, const auto& b) {return a >= 0 && b < 0; } // вот эта строчка?`

Answer (score 3):

*Компаратор*, сиречь функция, которая обеспечивает настройку сортировки. Она заменяет стандартное отношение "`a` меньше `b`" на пользовательское.

В данном случае `a` "меньше" `b`, если `a` не меньше нуля, а `b` меньше. Т.е. сначала идут положительные числа, а потом отрицательные.

Но мне этот компаратор не нравится — нет *строгого* отношения "меньше"... Так что вообще говоря, результаты могут быть несколько неожиданными :)

Answer (score 3):

Это лямбда выражение.
Если записать это в виде "нормальных" функций:

```
bool f(const auto& a, const auto& b)
{
    return a >= 0 && b < 0; 
}
```

Comment: Это не безымянные  функции(точно также std::function тоже не функция). Это лямбда выражение, которое создает безымянный prvalue  замыкающий  объект,  который  ведет себя как объект функции.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan понял, спасибо. исправил.

Answer (score 2):

Это третий доп. параметр, который указывает порядок сортировки. Этот параметр может быть лямбдой (как в данном примере) или функцией, которые принимают два параметра. Каждый раз `std::sort` посылает в эту лямбду два значение из контейнера, дальше идет логическое выражение, которое даст `true` или `false`.
Если выражение истинно, эти значения меняются местами, иначе - ничего не происходит. Что интересно, так этот вызов `std::sort` просто переносит отрицательные значение в конец. Это можно заменить на более элегантную конструкцию:

```
std::partition(std::begin(m), std::end(m), [](const auto& a) { return a >= 0; });
```

Comment: Я бы использовал  *std::remove_if(std::begin(m), std::end(m),
        [](int b) { return b < 0; });*

Comment: тоже вариант, кстати

Comment: Если учесть, что оператор  >= может быть не  определен  для многих типов, и что оператор меньше эффективней,  то это не то же вариант, а лучше вариант

Comment: @ARHovsepyan У них немного разный смысл. После `remove_if` отрицательные числа в конце массива могут не сохраниться, а после `partition` точно сохранятся.

Comment: `Что интересно, так этот вызов std::sort просто переносит отрицательные значение в конец`. Не просто переносит, порядок отрицательных между собой и неотрицательных между собой может быть нарушен. Вариант с `remove_if` работает совсем иначе. [Пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d0350df3f2cff4b).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, согласен, вы правы, тут нужно учесть, что remove_if  обеспечивает  объекты не удовлетворяющие предикату, а  за пределами  возвращающего итератора  результат не однозначен из за реализации, подходящий для данного алгоритма. Признаю, я ошибся. Спасибо за отзыв.